# Unable to render an array of values (React component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am building a test app to learn more about React and I have made an API call which gets a huge JSON object.
I was able to break this json into the parts that I need and now I have 10 arrays of 3 props each. I am able to send these 10 arrays in 3 props to another component, which needs to use these 3 props 10 times and render a `div class Card` each.

I can `console.log(this.props)` and it shows 10 different arrays with 3 props each,however, I cannot produce a same element 10 times.. I tried using map() but since my array is initially undefined, map() is not able to function properly either. Is there any thing in react like *ngFor in Angular ?

What is the best way to go about this?

*EDIT
Here's more code guys. Sorry still noobie here..

**ERROR : this.props.map is not a function**

```
 return(
    <div>            
 {this.props.map((data,i)=>{
       return(
          <li key={i}>{data.likes}</li>
           );
```

*EDIT 2
Soo I tried running map function with an if condition but the code still breaks the very moment the condition gets true..

```
render() { 
 if(this.props.url !== undefined){
     this.props.map((data,i) =>{
       return <li key={i}>{data.likes}</li>
     })
   }
```

---

My state method is :

```
state = {
        userId: undefined,
        likes: undefined,
        url: undefined
    }
```

and im setting my values on each data stream as follows :

```
const pics = await fetch(`${base_url}?key=${api_key}&q=${query}
            &img_type=photo&per_page=12`).then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })

            pics.hits.map((data) =>{
                return this.setState({
                    userId: data.user_id,
                    likes: data.likes,
                    url: data.webformatURL
                })
            })
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you with code we cannot see. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: You still haven't shown us how you're setting `props`, which is really important. Again: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2):

`this.props` won't have `map`, it's not an array. It's an object with a property for each property passed to your component. For instance:

```
<YourComponent foo="bar"/>
```

...will have `this.props.foo` with the value `"bar"`.

So if you're passing an array to your component, like this:

```
<YourComponent theArrayProperty={[{likes: 42},{likes:27}]} />
```

...then you need the name of that property:

```
return (
    <div>            
        {this.props.theArrayProperty.map((data,i) => {
            return (
                <li key={i}>{data.likes}</li>
            );
        })}
    </div>
    );
```

---

Side note: You can use a concise arrow function for the `map` callback instead:

```
return (
    <div>            
        {this.props.theArrayProperty.map((data,i) => <li key={i}>{data.likes}</li>)}
    </div>
    );
```

...and no need for the `()` if you put the opening tag on the line with `return` (you can't leave off the `(` if it's on the next line, but you probably knew that):

```
return <div>            
        {this.props.theArrayProperty.map((data,i) => <li key={i}>{data.likes}</li>)}
    </div>;
```

...but that's a matter of style.

Comment: Yess youre right that was a stupid mistake, but im still not able to get the function to work even with a Arrayproperty.. I get a TypeError saying that this.props.likes.map is not a function.

Comment: @YashankVarshney - For the third time: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score -1):

With little information that you have provided, my guess is that code fails at map() when you try to use it with undefined value.
Try adding a conditional check to render

{props && props.map([RENDER CODE HERE])}

Answer (score -1):

You can just make simple if statement to check if the array is not undefined, and then pass it to map function.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to set a defaultProps for an empty array.

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  arrProp: []
};
```

Comment: I did but it doesnt work either.. Also tried empty string at first.